# Chinese art seals and signature?

Tags: translation

I was gifted this rather lovely silk painting back in the 1990s from a friend. It came with some Hokusai prints , thus this MAY be Japanese. In which case, please ignore me.

If however, it IS Chinese, I wondered if anyone could translate it for me?

Thank you so much! x

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can only make out 錦(?)畫苑 - 松鶴 - (長?)樂畫

Comment: Thank you Tang Ho. I believe this is concerning aonghe paintings, but I can't get enough information to find out the artist

Comment: Songhe paintings even :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

錦城畫苑 = Jincheng (gorgeous city) studio

松鶴 = Pine and crane (It is the title of the painting, 松鶴 represent longevity and elegance)

(長?)樂畫

長樂 is the author,  畫 means draw

[image: 城]

[城](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%E5%9F%8E)

Comment: Tang Ho - You are a gentleman and a scholar. I appreciate this *very* much! You more than deserve the points.

Comment: 長 may refer to the fact that the painting is "long"?

Comment: @Barrie Reader There is an extra space between 長樂 and 畫. I am sure 長樂 is a name, However, I am only 80% sure it is stylized 長, so I put a question mark after it